# Issues with Spring cloud consul config while starting a Groovy app through Spring cloud cli

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I am Exploring Consul for discovery and config server. I have added the required dependencies and yml file is set up. When i try to start the server using spring cloud cli (Spring run .) I am getting the below error which i am unable to resolve. Any help is appreciated.

> Error :
>   "A component required a bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor' that could >not be found."

I tried to define this bean but when i start the app through spring cloud cli it is not recognizing it.

> Please see the code below

```
App.groovy

@Grab("spring-cloud-starter-consul-config")
@Grab("spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery")

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RestController
@Log
class Application{

@Autowired
Greeter greeter

int counter = 0

@RequestMapping(value = "/counter", produces = "application/json")
String produce() {
    counter++
    log.info("Produced a value: ${counter}")

    "{\"value\": ${counter}}"
}

@RequestMapping("/")
String home() {
    "${greeter.greeting} World!"
}

@RequestMapping(value = '/questions/{questionId}')
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultQuestion")
def question(@PathVariable String questionId) {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
        throw new RuntimeException('random');
    }
    [questionId: questionId]
}

def defaultQuestion(String questionId) {
   [questionId: 'defaultQuestion']
}

}

@Component
@RefreshScope
class Greeter {
@Value('${greeting}')
String greeting
}

bootstrap.yml

consul:
  host: localhost
  port: 8500
  config:
    enabled: true
    prefix: config
    defaultContext: master
    profileSeparator: '::'
    format: FILES
  discovery:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
    health-check-url: http://127.0.0.1:${server.port}/health
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to unwanted dependencies being pulled. 
Explicitly disabling spring cloud config and spring cloud discovery fixed it.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery:
        enabled: false
        serviceId: CONFIG
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```